# Filter no null rows using WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2014

```
SELECT        BC_ID, Procedure_Description, Test_result, Normal_Values
FROM            tbl_BC
WHERE        (NOT (Test_result LIKE '@Test_result = %'))
```

Hello.

I want to filter all not null in Test_result row, but with the code above all records in the datagridview will hide.

Comment: If you only want to display all rows that are not null you can use `where Test_result is not null`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but I think you want to ensure that NULL values are not included in your results.

Use `IS NOT NULL` to filter `NULL` values in T-SQL:

```
SELECT
    BC_ID,
    Procedure_Description,
    Test_Result,
    Normal_Values
FROM
    tbl_BC
WHERE
    Test_Result NOT LIKE @Test_Result + '%'
    AND
    TestResult IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @JaphetCompendioBatucan Can you post some example input and desired output data in your original question? Thanks!